# "Agree on" vs. "agree with" vs. "agree to"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, prepositions

What are the differences between "agree on", "agree with" and "agree to"?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The object is the difference.

- When you agree *with* someone/something, it means you accept the point of someone/something.

  > I agree with you.
  >
  > Matt does not agree with my answer.
- You agree *on* some issue or point of debate.

  > We agreed on this issue.
- You agree to demands/queries, or you agree to do something.

  > He agreed to my demands.
  >
  > He agreed to join me for the movie.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. (courtesy of Have Fun Slower)

Comment: Actually, you don't "**have to** agree *with* some person or group." -- that's both sarcastically and linguistically wrong.

Answer (score 13):

A quote from "A valency dictionary of English" (Herbst et al. 2004: 25), with some modifications:

**A**. *Agree* can mean 'be of the same opinion'

(i) People can **agree on** or **about** a particular topic or issue.

(ii) A person can **agree with** another person **on** or **about** a particular topic or issue.

(iii) A person can **agree that** something is the case.

**B.** *Agree* can mean 'consent'.

(i) A person or organisation can **agree to** or **with** something suggested.

(ii) A person or organisation can **agree to do** something suggested.

**C.** If two statements or versions of something **agree**, they are the same; if figures or calculations **agree**, they show the same result. Grammatical categories also **agree**, i.e. correspond in number etc.

**D.** *Agree* can mean 'come to a common conclusion'.

(i) People can **agree some course of action**, i.e. decide upon it.

(ii) People can **agree on** something as the result of a discussion.

(iii) People can **agree to do** something.

**E.** If something such as food or the climate **does not agree with** a person, it causes them problems.

Answer (score 10):

When two or more people agree **on** something, it means they have the same opinion about something being discussed. To agree **with** someone is to share a point of view with him/her, and to agree **with** an idea or proposal is to accept it and to believe that it's valid. Example use that includes both prepositions: *"He agreed **with** you **on** whether we should increase the salary."*

You use *"agree **to**"* to imply that a request was made and that the person towards whom the request was directed responded positively to that request -- i.e., he/she *agreed **to*** do whatever the requester was asking him to do. Example: *"She agreed **to** be my prom date."* (There are other, more slang and common phrasings to talk about proms, though.)